# Items failed in Preparing Transport/Transporting phase

Tags: 2013

Items failed during Preparing Transport/Transporting phase . No error log seen in Event Viewer or cd_transport logs. Noticed that publishing package is not being generated for the items that are failed. Restarting the CM database solved the issue.How to find why items were failed in that phase ? Will there be any logging in the CM database to verify or can it be found in any other logs? (Using Tridion 2013 SP1 version)

Comment: Is the fully specified URL to upload page returning a success message? `SDL Tridion HTTP Upload and Responder Servlet` ? Is this a new deployer or existing? Double/triple check configurations, ports. Are you using linux or windows as deployer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely reason for failure in transport phase is connectivity with deployer having issues.

For your error, since it is resolved by restarting CM, it seems you are transporting package on https to deployer and there were issues with certificate for https, which can be resolved by restart of service.

For checking error details you can look at following 3 location:

> 1. Publishing queue, click on failed state to see error.
> 2. Cd_transport log, which can be configured in transport service configure located in bin folder.
> 3. Tridion event log.

Comment: Thanks Hiren for your response. But I don't see any error details in the publishing queue when clicked on the failed state. cd_transport, event viewer also do not contain any details about the failed items. Issue got resolved by restarting CM database instance  not service.

Comment: This doesn't make sense because CM database issues would have failed rendering and it would not have failed on transport.

Comment: Okay Hiren,but how to find the rendering mode issues ? Consider there is no problem with the CM database , then what might be the reason that for few items bak files were created which were success and the items that were failed don't have the bak file created in the transactions folder.

Comment: If it was not database issue then it can't be resolved with database instance restart. In publishing queue, what was the last successful state that was being displayed at the time of failure.

Comment: It failed during "Transporting" phase

Comment: what about the tridion event viewer log file, did it contain any errors/warnings?

Answer (score 3):

The Publisher service is responsible for creating the transport package. In your case the package was not created hinting at an issue with the Publisher service.  The Publisher also places a heavy load on the Database as it tries to render the content with the templates, and somewhere in this 'conversation' between the publisher and database things went wrong.  Maybe the event viewer or log on the database server has some clues.  You can also check the publisher log if it was configured in the MMC snapin.

Answer (score 1):

To find the rendering mode issue, go to publishing queue and check as shown in following screenshot[image].

Comment: Thanks for the response Raj. I am unable to see any error message in the place you mentioned.